# TXF fonts in windows?

Tags: python, windows, fonts

Windows 10 has a preview function for TTF fonts.

Does there exist a program that does sorta the same but for TXF fonts?

Or does anyone know of a python function that can load such a font so I can write such a program myself, PILLOW didn't seem to support it.

Note: I tried showtxf.exe, but it show an image in too low resolution cannot really make out how the font looks.

Comment: What is a TXF font? And I ask that as someone who's written multiple OpenType parsers in various programming languages.

Comment: I think they are used on Sega consoles as the dreamSDK comes with a little program "showtxf.exe" to preview them, in a very low resolution though.
Also the GUI library PLIB can use them.
I don't know much more about them. There is a bunch of them that I would like to get previews of.

Comment: That realy, really, really sounds like it's just a privateª type of bitmap font. Kind of a stretch to expect a preview function for that in Windows, and/or a ready-built library. \[ªThere is no standard for bitmap fonts, everybody and his nephew may make up a format as they go. You will have to write the code yourself (and it'll only work with this particular fonts from Sega.).\]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm a little late. But I found this question AND the solution when searching for the answer to the same question.

txf seems to be a private file format for a bitmapped texture font which was/can be used in the context of GLUT by Marc Kilgard, an OpenGL toolkit in the late nineties.

The sourcecode and makefile are still around, along with a little instruction and a tool to generate(!) txf files from ttf font files. Also included is a txf-file viewer (source) where you are supposed to see all glyphs crammed into one coherent bitmap image, IIRC.

I found the source package at this link:

http://chateau-logic.com/content/ttf-txf-font-conversion